# Autocomplete and Syntax Highlighting do not work for matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, autocomplete, syntax-highlighting, hint

I am using VS Code for coding python and I am having an issue regarding Matplotlib: Usually Autocomplete and Syntax Highlighting work fine but not with matplotlib. There everything is just white and I get no proposals. See this example:
[image]

I am using a virtual environment with python 3.10.8.
Do you have any ideas on how to fix this issue? Thank you!

**Edit**:
It is not only a VS Code problem. I also do not get any hints in pycharm.

Comment: Maybe try restarting the language server for Python.  CTRL + SHIFT + P and search "Python: Restart Language Server"

Comment: @TimothyG. I tryed it but it did not solve the issue. Could it be that using `pip install matplotlib` in my virtual environment is not enough and I need to specify something more for vs code?

Answer (score 0):

> mpl.figure

> mpl.Axes

What you called is the method in the pyplot module in matplotlib. If you run your code, an error will also be reported.

Use the following code to declare your `mpl`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl
```

[image]
[image]

If the problem cannot be solved, please paste your import code. I will try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I do have the imports `import matplotlib as mpl` and `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`. When I run my code (`python -m my_package.my_module`) everything works as expected. I believe the issue is because of an incorecct integration of the virtual environment into vs code.

Comment: What language server did you use? I used Pylance, add the following codes to your settings.json: `"python.languageServer": "Pylance",`

Comment: It does not help. Here is my complete settings.json: `"editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true,
"github.copilot.enable": {...},
"editor.fontSize": 16,
"python.analysis.extraPaths": [...],
"python.venvPath": "C:\\Users\\my_user\\python_envs",
"python.languageServer": "Pylance",
"remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {...},
"editor.rulers": [ 110 ],`. Is there something else wrong? I then select my python interpreter by clicking on the bottom right button for python and selecting my venv in the popup. (The directory `python_envs` contains multiple venvs).

Comment: Have you restarted vscode? If it still doesn't work, I'm sorry that I don't know what else might cause this problem because I can't let this problem appear on my computer. Maybe submit this problem to this package's github is a good choice if pylance will give intellisense for other packages.

Comment: Yes I did a restart - did not help

Comment: It seems to be not only a VS Code problem. I also don't get any hints for matplotlib in pycharm.